# how would I make the openFileDialog open txt file in this case

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

I am trying to have
fname = QFileDialog(self,'Source Text','','txt(*.txt)')
run when you call the function openFileDialog
I have tried using a lambda instead of a normal function but that didn't work ethier
I am trying to make a cryptography program and am setting up the basic text upload system
I am currently trying to set fname to the file name

```
import sys

from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QFileDialog

from tkinter import filedialog

def Encrypt(SourceText):
    print (SourceText)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    
    
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(886, 487)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.Enter = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Enter.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        self.Enter.setObjectName("Enter")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Enter, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LayoutDirection.RightToLeft)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 886, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionUpload = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionUpload.setShortcutContext(
            QtCore.Qt.ShortcutContext.WindowShortcut)
        self.actionUpload.setMenuRole(QtGui.QAction.MenuRole.AboutQtRole)
        self.actionUpload.setObjectName("actionUpload")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionUpload)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.actionUpload.triggered.connect(lambda: self.Open("File Uploaded"))

    def clicked(self):
        Encrypt(self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText())

    def openFileDialog(self):
        fname = QFileDialog(self,'Source Text','','txt(*.txt)')


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.Enter.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter"))
        self.label.setText(_translate(
            "MainWindow", "Enter Text Below Or Upload File"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.actionUpload.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Upload"))
        self.actionUpload.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow","Ctrl+O"))


    def Open(self, text):
        openFileDialog()
        print (text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use `QFileDialog().getOpenFileName(parent, caption, path, filter)` instead of `QFileDialog(parent, caption, path, filter)`:

```
import sys

from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QFileDialog

from tkinter import filedialog


def Encrypt(SourceText):
    print(SourceText)


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(886, 487)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.Enter = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Enter.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        self.Enter.setObjectName("Enter")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Enter, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LayoutDirection.RightToLeft)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 886, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionUpload = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionUpload.setShortcutContext(
            QtCore.Qt.ShortcutContext.WindowShortcut)
        self.actionUpload.setMenuRole(QtGui.QAction.MenuRole.AboutQtRole)
        self.actionUpload.setObjectName("actionUpload")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionUpload)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.actionUpload.triggered.connect(lambda: self.Open("File Uploaded"))

    def clicked(self):
        Encrypt(self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText())

    def openFileDialog(self):
        fname, _ = QFileDialog().getOpenFileName(self, 'Source Text', '', 'Text files (*.txt)')

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.Enter.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter"))
        self.label.setText(_translate(
            "MainWindow", "Enter Text Below Or Upload File"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.actionUpload.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Upload"))
        self.actionUpload.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl+O"))

    def Open(self, text):
        self.openFileDialog()
        print(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```